# Android AppWidget, Massive layout discrepancy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm creating an App Widget, and I'm having a strange issue. In the Eclipse graphical layout editor, my widget's layout looks like this:

[image: How widget appears in Eclipse layout manager]

However, when I install it on an emulator/my phone, it looks like this:

[image: How widget appears on device emulator]

And here is the layout code in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/blackbg"
        android:layout_width="290dp" android:layout_height="145dp">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/clock_colon"
            android:layout_height="107dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:id="@+id/colon" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/num_0"
            android:layout_height="107dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/hour2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/colon" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/num_1"
            android:layout_height="107dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/hour1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/hour2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/num_3"
            android:layout_height="107dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/minute1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/colon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/num_2"
            android:layout_height="107dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/minute2"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/minute1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/clock_pm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/clock_ampm"
            android:layout_below="@id/minute2" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So what do you think? How come the numbers are getting cut off and spaced strangely like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting manually the `height` of your `RelativeLayout` and the `height` of your `ImageViews` to `107dp` and your images may not fit properly inside your `ImageView`. So you should consider the following:

- [Supporting Multiple Screens Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- Setting the scale of your `ImageView` to [`android:scaleType:centerInside`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
- You should also consider using `wrap_content` for your layout height and width instead of manually setting the dimensions in `dp`
- You can also try the attribute [`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds) for your `ImageViews` if they still don't get displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I had set the size for the container RelativeLayout. Apparently you can't do that.

Comment: is what I was telling you... and what do you mean you can't do that?

Comment: Oh, hey, you were telling me to do that. My apologies, answer accepted! I don't know where my brain goes sometimes